# ASP.NET Core post-publish not executed on Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, web-config, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have a pretty weird problem with deploying my simple application to Azure as App Service. The application is ASP.NET Core and React front-end. The deployment flow looks like this:

- I code, commit and push to development branch
- Visual Studio Team Services picks up the changes and start building process: [Build steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2vke.png), example publish step log: [log](http://humanaction.eu/public-files/publish-log.txt)
- Then after successful build, the release process picks up the artifacts and start Azure deploy.
- As a result: all already had worked a few days ago, but now web.config is not transformed with IIS integration tools, so its being left in its pristine state:

```
  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So, when you try to access the app service via url, it crashes with error 502 as a result. I verified by accessing the app service files and changing web.config by hand, that the application works fine with the correct web.config. My project.json:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0",
        "AutoMapper": "5.2.0",
        "AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection": "1.2.0",
        "HumanAction.Historykon.Configuration": "1.0.0-*",
        "HumanAction.Historykon.DataAccessLayer": "1.0.0-*",
        "HumanAction.Historykon.Domain": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "2.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
            "version": "1.0.1",
            "type": "build"
        },
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
            "version": "1.0.0-preview4-final"
        },
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
            "version": "1.0.1",
            "type": "platform"
        }
    },

  "tools": {
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
                            "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
            } 
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings.Dev.json",
      "appsettings.Qa.json",
      "appsettings.Live.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

The thing is: when I publish the application locally with Visual Studio, all is well, the web.config is correct, the application works.

Finally, the question: what went wrong? In before, I would like to stay in this version of sdk, but if there's no other option I will consider updating. Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Comment: have you noticed the error at the end of your build log? ```Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
2017-03-03T07:20:29.4468824Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
2017-03-03T07:20:30.4738821Z ##[section]Finishing: dotnet publish```

Comment: Hey! To be honest, I haven't noticed that, not sure why. Why is that assembly missing? I haven't had it included in project.json before and it worked, not sure why now its a problem. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new simple project?

Comment: No, it works for new simple project, there is my mistake hidden somewhere.

Comment: So, I have added `"Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils": "1.0.0",` to project.json, also I added argument to dotnet restore step `--no-cache`. No there is no exception in the build log, but the web.config is still not being transformed.

Comment: Is project.json of simple project the same as your project?

Comment: I modified my project with your project.json (removed HumanAction references and added some references), it works fine too. I shared it on the OneDrive: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AresBGZVYryjhSTjIBt-ftBdm3hx

Comment: have you run it on VSTS? It works locally for me too, I have some weird problems with hosted agents. I tried a few different approaches yesterday evening and no success. I'm starting to think about recreating the whole project.

Comment: @RichardRahl I tested with Hosted Agent, I think recreating the project can fix this issue, please post the result here after you done.

Comment: What's the result now?

Comment: Before I try to recreate the whole project I wan to try Microsoft support, will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools 1.0.0-preview2-final instead. Related thread: [Visual Studio Team Services asp.net core build for IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149958/visual-studio-team-services-asp-net-core-build-for-iis)

Comment: Hey, i'm already using this version. Have a look at project.json

Comment: @RichardRahl Do you use Hosted agent or on premise build agent?

Comment: starain-MSFT: Hosted agent